# Creating two linked objects before linked field has been generated by database - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to know if there is a way to add two linked objects to a database through entity framework before the linked field has been generated by the database.

I am still learning EF and I'm not exactly sure how to ask this question clearly so here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

I have two classes:

```
class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // generated by SQL Server
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

class SalesComment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public string Comment {get; set; }
}
```

Using fluent api in my 'dbcontext' class I link the two objects like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().HasMany(s => s.Comments).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.SaleId);
```

This works great, I can retrieve a Sale object from the database and I can loop through the comments linked to it by SaleId.

What I want to do is when creating a new Sale, add a Comment as I am creating it, with EF realising this is happening and adding the SaleId to the Comments table once it is generated by the database, something like:

```
using (MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase())
{
    var sale = db.Set<Sale>();
    sale.Add(new Sale
    {
        Foo = "Test",
        Bar = "Test",
        Comment.Add(new SalesComment .... //this is the line i'm not sure about
    });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is something like this possible? Or would I have to first save the Sale object to the database so that a SaleId is generated, then retrieve that object again so I can read the SaleId to use for a new SalesComment.

Comment: why don't you try and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
using (MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase())
{
    var sale = db.Set<Sale>();
    var saleComment = new SalesComment{Comment="Hello"};
    var saleToAdd = new Sale
    {
        Foo = "Test",
        Bar = "Test",
        Comments = new List<SalesComment> {saleComment}
    });

    sale.Add(saleToAdd);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // After saving changes, these 2 values will be populated and are equal
    var saleID = saleToAdd.Id;
    var saleCommentSaleId = saleComment.saleId;
}
```

You don't have to retrieve the object again if you cache it properly before adding it to the DbSet.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for and I did try something similar however on you line `Comments.Add(saleComment)` I get the error "The name 'Comments' does not exists in the current context. Invalid initializer member declarator", even though Intellisense suggests Comments as I type it!

Comment: @TomCarroll New up the comments with a `List`.